# How can I have multiple links on the same level as the main page in doxygen without breaking the link highlighting

Tags: javascript, html, css, doxygen

I am trying to make it where my links in doxygen on my tree-style navbar have multiple links on the same level as the main page. I was able to accomplish that by changing the order of links in the navtreedata.js . Now the problem is that by doing this I appear to have made it where it thinks everything on the first level of links is the index/mainpage as far as the navtree is concerned. It shows the index/mainpage with the blue highlight behind it as if it is the one I clicked. The page displays the right information but it looks weird. Even worse, I have some links I placed on the top level of links(same level as the main page)that have subpages. Whenever I click a subpage it folds up the foldout, which is really annoying. Anyone know how I can fix this? I am afraid I will need to modify the navtree.js or the html/css somewhere but I don't know much about javascript or HTML/CSS. I believe it is upset because my links no longer match up with the indexes they are given in the navtreeindex0.js.Also if anyone knows an easier way of accomplishing my goals without changing the navtreedata.js please let me know.

The javacript for my navetree since I was asked for code:

```
var NAVTREE =
[
  [ "Main page", "index.html", [
    [ "page 1", "page1.html", null ],
    [ "page2", "page2.html", [
      [ page3", "page3.html", null ],
      [ "page4", "page4.html", null],
      [ "page5", "page5.html", [
        [ "page6", "page6.html", null ],
        [ "page7", "page7.html", null ]
      ] ],
      [ "page8", "page8.html", null ]
    ] ],
    [ "page9", null, [
      [ "page10", "page10.html", null ]
    ] ],
    [ "page11", "page11.html", null ]
  ] ],

  [ "SECOND LEVEL MENU ENTRY", "sample-file-secondary.html", [
        [ "page 12", "page12.html", null ],
        [ "page 13", "page13.html", null ]
  ] ],
  [ "THIRD LEVEL MENU ENTRY", "sample-file-third.html"]


];

var NAVTREEINDEX =
[
".html"
];

var SYNCONMSG = 'click to disable panel synchronisation';
var SYNCOFFMSG = 'click to enable panel synchronisation';
```

Comment: You might want to show some code.

Comment: @Dshiz Ok I added the code that I modified to try and get more than one link on the same level as the main page. Not sure its going to help much though.